# theorems equivalent to the parallel postulate

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, euclidean-geometry, axioms

Is there a good survey article listing all the theorems of Euclidean geometry that are equivalent to the parallel postulate?

Comment: Do you mean all the theorems *in Euclid* equivalent to that postulate?  "Euclidean geometry" encompasses many theorems not in the surviving manuscripts (and of course infinitely many others...) so a complete list in this wider sense seems well out of reach.

Comment: A fairly decent list is in the book "Higher geometry" by Efimov (Mir eds.)

Comment: found this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_postulate#Logically_equivalent_properties  

Comment: In view of Noam's comment, I should clarify what I want, which is a pointer to the most comprehensive (and not too hard to find) existing list of theorems equivalent to the parallel postulate.  The Wikipedia article lists 14, but I suspect longer lists have been created.

Comment: It has been a while since I last looked, but I remember that M. J. Greenberg has a very long list of theorems equivalent to the parallel postulate in his book "Euclidean and non-Euclidean Geometries: Development and History".

Comment: Here's a list of 26 with a reference to the source of the list: http://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/junkyard/parallel-postulate.html

Comment: It sounds like he stopped counting when he ran out of letters to index them

Comment: The parallel line postulate is true is Euclidean geometry, so as long as you are doing Euclidean geometry, all true statements are logically equivalent to it.

Answer (score 2):

Doug Chatham's answer is the best I received; see [Theorem 23.7](https://books.google.com/books?id=_ynUBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA276) of George E. Martin's "The Foundations of Geometry and the Non-Euclidean Plane".

Comment: @James Propp:  Greenberg's list is considerably longer, but now I remember that the list is not actually in the textbook itself; it's in the teacher's supplement to the textbook.  One of the projects given in Greenberg's textbook is exactly to compile the longest list one can of theorems equivalent to the parallel postulate.  The list in the teacher's supplement is intended to help the teacher cope with the lists that the students' projects will generate.